# printing a byte array

Tags: python, arrays

Can someone please explain this Python 3.5 behavior. . .

```
 >>> c = bytearray.fromhex("000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F")

 >>> c  
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f')

 >>> hex(c[10])  
'0xa'
```

Why are items 9 and 10 printed as \t and \n respectively?
And item 13 as \r ?
ie. instead of \x09 \x0a and \x0d ?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @Isaac "... explain this Python 3.5 behavior ..." also, the `python` tag.

Comment: Those are tab, newline, and carriage return characters, respectively - being shown in a more compact and potentially more meaningful fashion than hex escapes.

Comment: @Quelklef it didnt have this info in the question initially

Comment: Look at: https://www.asciitable.com/
09 is tab, 0A is newline feed

Comment: @Isaac Sure; sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\t` *is* `x09` and `\n` *is* `x0A` and `\r` *is* `x0D`; the are equivalent in memory. See the following from https://www.asciitable.com/:

[image: ASCII codes.]

You are creating a byte array containing a bunch of data. When you ask Python to print that data, for most of the bytes, it uses the general form `\x__`. But it recognizes the three that you have pointed out and prints it in a more meaningful form, namely `\t`, `\n`, and `\r`.